# extract poster image from quicktime movie? is there an easier format to do this?

Tags: video, image-processing, webserver, frame, quicktime

i've been searching the net for a way to extract the set poster image from a quicktime movie on the backend once a file has been uploaded. is there an effective way to do this? or is there a way to grab a specific frame as a visual? i would imagine a script could comb the file for the specific attribute value pairs and image content, no? Any help in this subject would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a reference to the quicktime movie format ? From that we can extract this poster frame. I would think it has some kind of tag that indicates which frame is the poster frame.

Comment: i just searched for an api and found this: http://heroinewarrior.com/quicktime/ for linux... perhaps this will do the trick?

Comment: Most likely you need to read XMP tags: http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/XMP.html

Comment: thanks! i did a little bit more digging and found this: http://xmpphptoolkit.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I've looked into this a bit more and it looks like the poster frame is simply indicated by the poster time tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the poster frame is always part of the `.mov` video, you can begin by extract the exif tag `PosterTime`. The value of this tag indicates where in the video the poster frame is, by default it is at time 0 (i.e., the first frame). Then you can extract the frame by some program that understands this video format, `ffmpeg` is a good such program.

As an example, we can use `exiftool` to extract the value for the tag `PosterTime`. I manually changed the poster frame of some video I had around, then using `exiftool` as

```
exiftool -PosterTime -b somevideo.mov
```

I get:

```
0.013333333333333
```

This means the poster frame can be found at the second ~0.013 (that is, between the second 0 and second 1 if it is not clear). Now we can extract the single frame at that time using `ffmpeg`:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:00.013 -i somevideo.mov -frames 1 posterframe.jpg
```

Now, note that at http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/QuickTime.html you will see there is also a tag called `PreviewPICT`. This seems to indicate there could be something else to represent the poster frame, but I'm not sure if this tag is actually used for this purpose.

Comment: thank you for this excellent answer! i would imagine that 'PreviewPICT' would be for an manual image file insertion done by a user in quicktime player (pro). this is great. xmp support also looks like a great approach to file resource information management on the server.

Comment: How did you manage to change the PosterTime value? It doesn't look like exiftool nor ffmpeg are able to write to it.